# Fetching Data From Facebook Page

Tags: php, json, facebook, video

I don't know where to start as there is nothing on google regarding this all I know is that that it's possible to do this via JSON Data?

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=vb.553980194682224&type=2

I know I have no examples but this seems very complex and probably impossible but thought I ask here before I give up and know that it's currently impossible.

Comment: -1 for lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the graph interface.

https://graph.facebook.com/634887656591477

I had to work a lot of this out as there is very little out there about it..... it works like this.

Get a token using your facebook app credentials

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials

{0} = App Id
{1} = App Secret

Then you get a response that looks like

token=123asdqweioojfowie123324joijsaodjfoewi

Use the token to then request a json feed....

https://graph.facebook.com/634887656591477/videos?token={0}

The documentation that you're looking for

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Note that if you try to do this client side you'll get a security issue. The way I got around that was to load it server side and then pipe it out to the javascript client, thus making it look like it's from the same url.

Comment: it's asking for a user access token now where would I get the user access one from?
Thanks ;)

Comment: That's the token I mentioned before, you'll need to create an app so you can get your app id and app secret to request it using the method listed above. It's a 2 step process.